# How to override a BlueprintNativeEvent function in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to implement parts of a function marked with `BlueprintNativeEvent` in a derived class in C++, while others implement parts of that function in a derived Blueprint class.

However, the function seems to be not a `virtual` function, so I don't know how to `override` it in C++ (in Blueprint it works though). Example from GameplayAbilitySystem:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, Category="Calculation")
float CalculateBaseMagnitude(const FGameplayEffectSpec& Spec) const;
```

How to override this in a derived class in C++?

Answer (score 5):

Before compilation, [UnrealHeaderTool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/BuildTools) generates the `virtual` function for a `BlueprintNativeEvent` in the base class. The example from above would look like:

```
virtual float CalculateBaseMagnitude_Implementation(const FGameplayEffectSpec& Spec) const;
```

So in the derived C++ class, override (and implement) that function as usual in C++:

```
class PROJECT_API UGMMCCustom : public UGameplayModMagnitudeCalculation
{
    float CalculateBaseMagnitude_Implementation(const FGameplayEffectSpec& Spec) const override
    {
        return {}; // Add your custom implementation in the cpp file.
    }
}
```